# Invalid timestamp received from non-stop SQL

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, hp-nonstop, sqlmp

I have a problem with the returned date from my database. I use an hp-nonstop SQL/mp database. My problem is that the time after the seconds isn't formatted correctly. However it is not that the date gets truncated after the milliseconds, there is litteraly three zeros that appears out of nowhere.

For example

Expected date

2017-08-08 11:11:11.123456

Received date

2017-08-08 11:11:11.000123

I do not think my problem come from my request since even by doing a simple

select * from table where something="something"

I still have an error.

I use the 2.10 version of non-stop SQL by H-P, if it can help.

Someone already had the same problem as me http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/2747 , but he was using another DLL.

Is it a known bug from non stop SQL and ODBC ? that can be solved by updating the dll ? I found nothing on the H-P website.

Comment: What is the column definition on the NonStop ? The DATETIME data type on there will have to be converted to TIME or whatever the client side expects and zero-filling may occur (according to the NonStop ODBC Server Reference Manual).

Comment: @AndySimpson The data type is year to fraction(6) and the client side is converted to datetime. However, you said that it is documented, but when I searched for it I found nothing ... Do you mind giving me a link to the doc ?

Comment: The manual is here: https://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=4201311&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c02128639   See page 3-10 for the comment about zero-fill. Does the same thing happen if the client-side is data type timestamp ?